# Qt for Embedded Linux or Qt Enterprise Embedded?

Tags: qt, qt4.8

I need to develop an application for a board (ARM 8), running embedded Linux (probably Angstrom – yet to be decided). I’ve been Googling and I’m confused about a few things.

It seems for embedded, I have to use [Qt for Embedded Linux](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-linux.html) (qt-4.8). I also see a [Qt Enterprise Embedded](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-for-Embedded-Development/Qt-Enterprise-Embedded/).

I’m confused between the two. What’s the more current way to go with Qt for embedded linux and what’s the major difference between the two?

Also, I downloaded the Qt SDK and followed the [instructions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-install.html) to build and install the SDK on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system. However, I do not see QtCreator, QtDesigner, and QtQuick Designer anywhere on my system. According to the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/how-to-learn-qt.html) I should have gotten all of these tools, including [qtdemo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtdemo.html) application after building the sdk.

Finally, I do not see a version 4.8 of the QtCreator. The link in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/how-to-learn-qt.html) page (Tools to Install) is broken. Can I use the latest QtCreator with Qt 4.8 SDK?

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please reduce your question to one. As for Qt embedded, you could just use the upstream codebase for free. There is no need for enterprise embedded if you do not need dedicated support from Digia. The former is Qt 4. I would really suggest against that as Qt 5 is a much improved platform for embedded.

Comment: I second Laszlo's advice to go with Qt 5. Also, there's no such thing as a "4.8" version of Qt Creator. The newest one at the moment is 3.1. The Qt Creator is an IDE and as such it's a standalone project. Yes, it happens to use the Qt framework in its implementation :) The most you'll find by the name of "Qt SDK" is an obsolete thing for Qt 4.7.x. These days, Qt SDK is just called Qt. Precompiled Qt downloads include Qt Creator. If you are building it from scratch, you need to build Qt first (designer will be there), then download creator sources and build those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Qt Enterprise Embedded is a commercial version of Qt for embedded devices If you need support you can buy it from Digia.

The Qt libraries 4.8.5 for embedded Linux is also available for download. It uses Compact and Efficient Windowing System (QWS). It writes directly to the Linux framebuffer, eliminating the need for the X11 windowing system and saving memory.

You can use Qt5 for embedded devices as long as you have a good graphics stack. There is no specific Embedded prebuild available for Qt5 because QWS was dropped in favour for Qt Platform Abstraction. So, Qt does not ship with a windowing system anymore, it expects the OS to provide one (or at least some display devices like directFB etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your lucid answer. Some clouds have indeed been cleared. I installed QtCreator 3.1 along with Qt for Embedded Linux (4.8.5) but I don't see the qtdemo app anywhere, nor do I see any of the examples in QtCreator. The examples "wizard" is an empty page. Would you happen to have any pointers on how to get started. I've followed the instructions at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-install.html verbatim, but it does not help.

Comment: If recommend to use Qt5. It's much more better and also dos not use QWS which is obsolete.

Comment: To be fair, directFB is not a display device, but I think the question is a bit opinion based and/or too broad. It depends on many factors what one would pick up out of the available options.